# Python - Unknown command: 'supervisor'

Tags: python, django, supervisord

i'm tring to use django-supervisor

I've created a new virtualenv 'supervisor_env'
I've installed django
I've created a new project in supervisor_env called supervisor_project

```
YoBre-work:virtualenvs YoBre$ mkvirtualenv supervisor_env
New python executable in supervisor_env/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............done.
Installing pip...............done.
(supervisor_env)YoBre-work:virtualenvs YoBre$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.5.1.tar.gz (8.0MB): 8.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
Installing collected packages: django
  Running setup.py install for django
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 644 to 755

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
    changing mode of /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/bin/django-admin.py to 755
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
(supervisor_env)YoBre-work:virtualenvs YoBre$ django-admin.py startproject supervisor_project
(supervisor_env)YoBre-work:virtualenvs YoBre$ python supervisor_project/manage.py supervisor
Unknown command: 'supervisor'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I followed this guide ([Django-supervisor](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-supervisor/)) but I'm stuck at the first command

I also tried to install supervisor but i get the same result

```
(supervisor_env)YoBre-work:virtualenvs YoBre$ pip install supervisor
Downloading/unpacking supervisor
  Downloading supervisor-3.0.tar.gz (459kB): 459kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package supervisor

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./supervisor_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg (from supervisor)
Downloading/unpacking meld3>=0.6.5 (from supervisor)
  Downloading meld3-0.6.10.tar.gz (41kB): 41kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package meld3

Installing collected packages: supervisor, meld3
  Running setup.py install for supervisor

    Skipping installation of /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/__init__.py (namespace package)
    Installing /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth
    Installing echo_supervisord_conf script to /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/bin
    Installing pidproxy script to /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/bin
    Installing supervisorctl script to /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/bin
    Installing supervisord script to /opt/virtualenvs/supervisor_env/bin
  Running setup.py install for meld3

Successfully installed supervisor meld3
Cleaning up...
(supervisor_env)YoBre-work:virtualenvs YoBre$ python supervisor_project/manage.py supervisor
Unknown command: 'supervisor'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

someone has never competed in this venture? Thank you all

Comment: However, it looks like your `manage.py` doesn't have the `django-supervisor` app installed. Did you add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` at all?

Comment: hi Martijn.. pip install supervisord
No distributions at all found for supervisord
pip install supervisord No distributions at all found for supervisorctl

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS... this is interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *add* the Django Supervisor application to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your settings module. Quoting the documentation:

> To get started, just include "djsupervisor" in your INSTALLED_APPS and drop a "supervisord.conf" file in your project directory, right next to the main manage.py script.

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ("djsupervisor",)
```

Comment: thanks Martijn for your answer. I've added the djsupervisor in my INSTALLED_APPS list, but i don't know where i find supervisor.conf. Do you know? :)

Comment: The documentation tells you to create one, in the same location as the `manage.py` script. It gives you a sample below the sentence I quoted.